# How can I make a cheap and simple straight and level recovery device for an RC airplane?

Tags: autopilot

I am a new RC pilot and I crash my RC aircraft a lot. I was thinking of a cool device which would be like training wheels for a plane: a device to return the plane to straight and level flight at the touch of a button.

I understand that I can do that with an autopilot but they are over \$100 and have more features than I need. I was thinking of something like a $2 6DOF MPU-6050 3 Axis Gyro With Accelerometer Sensor Module and an Arduino.

I'm thinking the Arduino would intercept the servo controls and when activated, it would use the data from the gyro to correct pitch and roll.

Does this sound feasible?

Comment: Are you familiar with Arduplane/Arducopter? Sounds like what you want to do already exists.

Comment: This question isn't really on topic on this forum.

Comment: Depending on your experiences and abilities  with the arduino and  the other hardware, it definitely sounds feasible. Be careful to not introduce too high AoA when programming the recovering maneuver.

Answer (score 1):

Hobbyzone SAFE technology may interest you, and it can be had for a reasonable budget.
The RC groups internet site may be good as well.

I include this answer on Aviation Stack Exchange to hold out the possibility that such
devices may be considered for full scale aircraft as well in the future.  They are able to almost instantaneously recover an aircraft from out of control to wings level with a push 
of a button.  Videos of this function are impressive.